# Ease formulas with velocities?

Tags: spline

Looking for simple ease in and ease out formulas or code that accept start or end velocity. (i.e. ease in from start position to end position over x frames starting with a velocity of 1. or 4.5 or ..) This is just for 1D.

Every ease formula I see on the internet assumes a start velocity of zero for ease in and an velocity of 0 for an ease out.

I can use 0-1 for time and distance and can scale the velocity accordingly.

Comment: To what language does this question pertain?